# how to move my one b2body attached with another b2body

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

i am very new to cocos2d ,i have started working with rope physics.i am using vrope class for creating ropes.i have implemented one rope attached with one polygon shaped b2body ,now i have fixed one end of my rope on top of the screen and one end with my polygon shaped dynamic b2body , it looks like it's hanging in air.now what i want is by applying some force on my b2body(dynamic body) , i want it falling down from top to bottom means i want to move my this body1 which is attached with rope towards ground along with that rope , i am trying like this :applying  force on my b2body :

in my update() method :

```
   body1->ApplyForce(b2Vec2(0.0 , 9.8 * body1->GetMass()*100 ), body1->GetWorldCenter());
```

but ,somehow this not working .

i searched a lot on this but still i don't find anything which can help me for this . it would be appreciated if any kind of help.

Comment: Can you post VRope class code

Comment: Vrope Class  : https://github.com/gregharding/VRope

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the body fall along with the rope. Then before you apply some force to that body1, instead of attaching a static body at other end, attach the body with very small dynamic body. In this way the body1 will fall down along with the rope

Comment: i have used b2RopeJoint kind of joints for creating my ropes , i guess , it may be not giving the elastic kind of effect because of this ropejoint ..still i am not sure .